# Java Sockets nonblocking read

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using a DataInputStream to read characters/data from a socket.

I want to use .readUnsignedShort(); and have it throw an exception if there isn't 2 bytes to read. Should I subclass the DataInputStream and override the methods adding the exceptions, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want something quick and dirty, try [inputStream.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29).

```
if (stream.available() < 2) {
    // throw it
}
```

If you want true non blocking reads and callbacks when data is available, I think Pablo's answer is better.

Comment: I found this by googling "nonblocking sockets", but all I really wanted was to poll the socket for incoming data without blocking the thread. To think it'd be so simple, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think Java NIO non-blocking classes are your best choice. Check [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) class and its related code samples.

But be careful, when you issue your read command, it might be the case that bytes are not available yet, but that doesn't mean that the will **never** arrive to your socket...

Answer (score 2):

```
void readButDoNotBlockForALongTime(java.net.Socket socket) {
    int someTimeout = 1000;
    socket.setSoTimeout(someTimeout);
    try {
        // read as much as you want - blocks until timeout elapses
    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // read timed out - you may throw an exception of your choice
    }
}
```

This is a simple way to block for only as long as you want.

> setSoTimeout(int timeout): Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

For a more elegant solution, you may consider using NIO.

Comment: I don't think having an exception be thrown and caught every 1000ms is elegant

Comment: Exactly. It's better than opening up the program for DOS attacks, but using NIO would be even better.

Comment: I agree, @StealthRabbi. Removing the word elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the input ends before supplying two bytes it will throw EOFException. If there is no input available() will return zero, although it can also return zero if there *is* input in some circumstances (e.g. SSL).